# How to create ISO8583 Meesage from XML using j8583

Tags: java, xml, iso8583, j8583

Using http://j8583.sourceforge.net/ I have parsed ISO message to XML in Java.

**ISO to XML:**

```
 <j8583config>
 <parse>
  <PROCESSINGCODE>000000</PROCESSINGCODE> 
  <SYSTEMTRACEAUDITNUMBER>000001</SYSTEMTRACEAUDITNUMBER> 
  <Cardacceptorterminalidentification>3239313130303031</Cardacceptorterminalidentification> 
  <Reservednational>001054455354204D45535347</Reservednational> 
  <Networkmanagementinformationcode>0301</Networkmanagementinformationcode> 
  </parse>
  </j8583config>
```

Now I need to do vice-versa. I need to create ISO message from XML.

Can someone please guide for this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

j8583 doesn't do that. You'll have to parse the XML yourself, create an `IsoMessage` and set the fields you want from the values in the XML fields.

At most, you could transform the XML to something resembling a message template, then create a `MessageFactory` and create a message with it, but that sounds terribly inefficient.

Perhaps a XSLT transformation could do the trick?

Comment: How would XSLT transformation help with this? Would it transform xml values to binary or something?

Comment: It would transform the XML file to an ISO8583 message, which you could then parse with your `MessageFactory` if you add the message type and bitmap yourself. But it's just a guess.

Comment: I found some code here: http://read.pudn.com/downloads141/sourcecode/java/612948/src/j8583/example/Example.java__.htm But it has binary/hex inputs. Can something like this work with xml input?

Comment: I found some code here: http://read.pudn.com/downloads141/sourcecode/java/612948/src/j8583/example/Example.java__.htm But it has binary/hex inputs. Can something like this work with xml input?

Comment: I have followed above link and able to set fields, but not bale to set bitmaps. How j8583 generate an iso message from anything like even from csv... can you please help?

Comment: j8583 does not parse csv or xml. It only parses ISO8583.